# Alternate definition for a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185587/what-actually-is-a-polynomial) Math SE question, and found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples) Wikipedia page.
Would it be apt to define a polynomial, as one whose Maclaurin Series is itself?

If not, why so?

Comment: Would you consider that the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ is itself, given that they both give the same value for all $x$? Would you consider the Maclaurin series for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ to be itself?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page that you link to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples) is confused and confusing. The authors don't make clear the distinction between a (formal) polynomial and a polynomial function.