# Polynomials with complex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am reading a book called College Algebra and it defines polynomials as an expression of the form $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ...+ a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ where $a_j$ are real numbers ( I'll stop the definition there). Does polynomials only have real coefficients or it can be complex numbers?

I asked this on a wrong place (Cross Validated) my bad.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Polynomials can be defined in any ring.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185587/what-actually-is-a-polynomial/2185648#2185648

Answer (score 0):

Polynomials can also have complex coefficients. There is actually quite a bit of work related to the topic. See, for example, [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-9171-5_4) or [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255985460).

An example of such a polynomial would be

$$(42+42i)x^2+(7+i)x.$$

The roots of the above polynomial are at $$x=0 $$ 
and 
$$ x = -\frac{2}{21} + \frac{i}{14}.$$

So, nobody hinders you to create polynomials with complex coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, it's better to state over *which* ring the polynomial is defined.

> A polynomial in $X$ *over a ring $R$* is defined as $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n = a_kX^K$, where $a_k \in R$ for $k \in \{0,\dots,n\}$.

In particular, a polynomial over $\Bbb{R}$ admits only real coefficients, whereas a polynomial over $\Bbb{C}$ admits complex coefficients.

---

Remarks: For pedagogical reasons, when one find [roots](/questions/tagged/roots) (of [polynomials](/questions/tagged/polynomials)) in [algebra-precalculus](/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), one usually focus on *real* roots and discard the complex ones, especially in exercises of [quadratic-equation](/questions/tagged/quadratic-equation).  I *guess* it's a possible reason that your *College Algebra* book only consider polynomials with real coefficients.  Things will become clearer when you move on to [abstract-algebra](/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra).

Comment: Is there a name for an analogue sum when the coefficients can be elements of a vector space (and $X$ a scalar) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't have an idea.  Say, a finite-dimensional $\Bbb{R}^n$, but I'm not sure how to make sense of multiplication.  If it's the ring of matrices, surely that makes sense, but still I don't know whether there's a special name for that.

Comment: Just scalar multiplication.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry I don't know a special name for that.