# Quick question on polynomial notation (from the perspective of rings)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, notation

I am reading some chapters about polynomials in the context of ring theory and am trying to develop some familiarity with the concept.

After reading this post, [What actually is a polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185587/what-actually-is-a-polynomial/2185648), I certainly have a better understanding. However, [one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2185648/242) had an example where I stumbled on the notation justification...here is an excerpt from said answer:

---

[image: Notation]

---

My confusion is from the very last line...where the author states that:

$$
(0, -2y^2 + 6y^3 , \color{#c00}{4y^3}) = ((0), (0, 0, -2, 6), \color{#c00}{(0, 4)})
$$

The left side of the equation makes sense, for if $X$ is the symbol of interest, then the $x^0$ coefficient has a $0$ in front of it, the $x^1$ symbols have $-2y^2 +6y^3$ coefficients in front of them, etc.

The right side of the equality is where I am stuck. I assume that this is now rewriting the left side notation by *embedding* $Y$ as the symbol of interest.

For example, in examining $-2y^2+6y^3$, the leading coefficient of $y^0$ is $0$, of $y^1$ is $0$, of $y^2$ is $-2$ and of $y^3$ is $6$...which would produce the notation of $(0,0,-2,6)$.

Following the same notation strategy, shouldn't $\color{#c00}{4y^3}$ be expressed as $(0,0,0,4)$ instead of $\color{#c00}{(0,4)}$? Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - and have therefore understood the abstraction involved.