# What are polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I looked on a website and it says that terms that are divided by a variable could not be called a polynomial, but when i looked at my textbook there's a section in my book called division of polynomials and in there the terms that are divided by a variable is stated as a polynomial. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: Not clear. How does your textbook define a polynomial? Can you provide the exact wording of the statement you are querying?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What actually is a polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2185587)

Comment: I take "division of polynomials" to mean dividing one polynomial by another to get a polynomial quotient and a polynomial remainder. Much like when you divide the integer $8$ by the integer $3$, you get $8/3$, which is not an integer, but you can phrase it as quotient $2$, remainder $2$, and those are both integers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh how is it that by calling them with the expression quotient and remainder, it is a polynomial?

Comment: It's exactly as with integers; if you divide $8$ by $3$, you get a quotient $2$, which is an integer, and a remainder $2$, which is an integer; $8/3$ isn't an integer, but that's irrelevant. Same exact thing happens with polynomials.

Comment: Is that OK, Dixon?

Comment: Are you still here, Dixon?

Comment: yes thank you for the explanation