# What does this definition of a polynomial mean?

Tags: polynomials

In a book I am reading, there is the following definition for a polynomial:

> A function $p: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is called a
> *polynomial* with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ if there exists $a_0, \ldots, a_m \in \mathbb{F}$ such that
>
> $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \ldots + a_mz^m$
>
> for all $z \in \mathbb{F}$.

However there aspects of this that do not make sense to me. For example, I can not think of any examples where you have a polynomial $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \ldots + a_mz^m$, with coefficients $a_0, \ldots, a_m \in \mathbb{F}$ but for *only some* $z \in \mathbb{F}$? Does that even make sense?

What precisely is this definition saying, as it seems to differ slightly (at least in terms of wording) from other definitions, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2185613/799831).

Comment: Well, is $1+x+sin(\pi\cdot x)$ a polinomial?
Take $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @Phicar No, but isn't that just because it isn't written in the form $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \ldots + a_mz^m$?

Comment: One thing the definition seems to exclude is piecewise functions, that are defined as a polynomial for part of the domain, and some other kind(s) of functions elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition does not define what a polynomial is; it defines what it means for a function to be polynomial. The definition above could be written as follows:

> A function $f: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is called a
> *polynomial* with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ if there exists a polynomial $p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ such that $f(x) = p(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}.$

The function $p(z) = \sin z$ satisfies the condition that there are $a_0, \ldots, a_m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots + a_m z^m$ for *only some* $z \in \mathbb{R}.$ One can for example take $m=0,\ a_0=0$ and those "some" $z$ to be $\{n\pi \mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$ But there are no $a_0, \ldots, a_m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots + a_m z^m$ for *all* $z \in \mathbb{R}.$ Therefore $p$ is not a polynomial function.