# Definition of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, definition

In the wikipedia, they define polynomial as follows:

> In mathematics, a polynomial is an expression consisting of indeterminates (also called variables) and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and positive-integer powers of variables.

Then if is there operations of differential, integral, etc. in the expression (for example)

$1+\frac{dy}{dx}$

then aren't expressions which have differential or integration like above can't be considered polynomial?

Comment: No, also $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: do you mean $1+\frac{dy}{dx}$ is polynomial? @Dietrich Burde

Comment: No. But you can write it as polynmial in $z=\frac{dy}{dx}$, namely as $f(z)=1+z$.

Comment: you mean if the expression is polynomial, then there isn't any differentatial and integral like $\frac{dy}{dx}$. But if differentatial or integration is expressed another variable like z, it can be polynomial. right?

Comment: Yes, just follow closely the definition you have. Here $z$ is our indeterminate or variable.

Comment: The trick is the word "indeterminate."

Comment: @DietrichBurde If you say $z=\frac{dy}{dx},$ then $z$ is not an indeterminate. I know what you are trying to say, but I think it might be more confusing to OP than helpful.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185587/what-actually-is-a-polynomial/2185648#2185648

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the concept you are looking for is
of [differential polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra#Differential_polynomials).

> A differential polynomial over a differential field $K$ is a formalization of the concept of differential equation such that the known functions appearing in the equation belong to $K$ and the indeterminates are symbols for the unknown functions.

This extends the idea of a polynomial to include differentiation
operations (actually termed "derivations") applied to variables.

A more precise definition of polynomial from Wikipedia
is in [polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring)

> In mathematics, especially in the field of algebra, a polynomial ring or polynomial algebra is a ring (which is also a commutative algebra) formed from the set of polynomials in one or more indeterminates (traditionally also called variables) with coefficients in another ring, often a field.

However, while this definition is useful in abstract algebra, it
is not what is commonly used in practice. A key idea is that of
a polynomial expression **relative** to some given set of other
expressions. That is, for example, $\cos(x)^2 + \sin(x)^2 - 1$
is a polynomial expression relative to $\{\cos(x),\sin(x)\}.$
Thus, another example is that $1 + \frac{dy}{dx}$ is a polynomial
expression relative to $\{\frac{dy}{dx}\}.$

Comment: It's not at all clear that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, is my question ambiguous?

Comment: i think this explanation is helpful, but i'm sorry i can't this completely. i'm only wondering 'is it possible differential operation can be in the polynomial??'

Comment: @김형주 Anything can be a polynomial if you use a loose enough definition of polynomial. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

The key is that there is a difference between a polynomial and a polynomial function.

Of particular importance is the notion of an indeterminate.

$1+z$ is a polynomial, with $z$ an indeterminate. $1+\frac{dy}{dx}$ is an evaluation of the related polynomial function at $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

The distinction between polynomial and polynomial function is somewhat (but not entirely) irrelevant when talking about polynomials with real or complex coefficients, because, given two such polynomials, they are equal if and only if the functions are always equal.

But with coefficients over finite rings, or rings with zero divisors, it is possible that two different polynomials can be associated with the same polynomial function on that ring.

The prototypical case is the ring $R=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,$ where $p$ is prime. Then $f(x)=x^{p}$ and $g(x)=x$ are two different polynomials but they are equal as polynomial functions on $R.$

So mathematicians define a concept of "indeterminate." Given a commutative ring $R,$ we can define rings $R[x]$ or $R[x,y,z]$ or $R[x_i]_{i=1}^{\infty}.$ These rings are the rings of polynomials, with, respectively, indeterminate $x$, or $x,y$ and $z,$ or $x_1,x_2,\dots.$

In these rings, we often write polynomials like $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2,$ looking like function definitions, but the variables are not meant to represent specific values. They are abstractions.

Now, given a polynomial $f\in R[x_1,\dots,x_n],$ we also have a polynomial function $\overline f:R^n\to R,$ which assigns to each $(r_i)_{i=1}^n\in R^n$ a value equal to what you would think of as the evaluation of that polynomial on $(r_1,\dots,r_n).$

But even more generally, given a homomorphism $R\to S,$ where $S$ is another commutative ring, we also get a polynomial function $\overline f:S^n\to S.$

For a simple example, if $R$ is the ring $\mathbb Z$ of integers, and $S$ is the ring $\mathbb C,$ of complex numbers, then we can evaluate $f(x,y)=2x+4xy+y^2\in\mathbb Z[x,y]$ as a polynomial function of complex numbers.

So a single polynomial actually can define a lot of functions.

Rings of polynomials are interesting, because they are the "simplest" commutative ring which contains which contain $R$ and the indeterminates. This can be made rigorous by showing a certain "universal property," but you can think of it as the smallest commutative ring of expressions formed by elements of $R$ and the indeterminates, using $+$ and $\times$ as your only operation.

---

(Note that, if we have infinitely many indeterminates, each polynomial will still only be a finite expression, and thus cannot use all the indeterminates.)

Comment: i think this explanation is helpful, but i'm sorry i can't this completely. i'm only wondering 'is it possible differential operation can be in the polynomial??'

Comment: No, differentials cannot be considered polynomials. There are extensions to polynomials that allow such things, but polynomials themselves only support $+$ and $\times.$

Comment: There is a separate notion of the derivative of polynomials. Given polynomials in $x,y,z$ we can define the derivative of the polynomial in terms of $x,y,$ and $z.$ For example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+xy+y^2)=2x+y.$  But this definition assumes $x,y,z$ are independent, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y=0.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, then you mean it is impossible differential operation is in the polynomial, but it is possible in separate notion of the derivative of polynomials. right?

Comment: Derivatives of polynomials are not elements of the ring of polynomials. They are operations on the ring of polynomials. Ultimately, a polynomial is something that can be written with just the binary operations $+$ and $\times,$ plus the elements of $R$ and the indeterminates. Derivatives of polynomials are externally defined, not an intrinsic part of the ring of polynomials.